# How to fix the following error in php?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a two piece of code for Regions and Categories. They are exactly the same. The code for Category works, but "Region" returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getRegion() on null in C:\wamp64\www\site\catalog\controller\module\latest.php on line 81
```

// Region

```
$product_region = array();
$regions = $this->model_profile_profile->getProductRegions($result['product_id']);
foreach ($regions as $region_id) {

print_r($region_id); // !!! ($region_id = 2) !!! $region_id is not empty !!!
    $region_info = $this->model_account_region->getRegion($region_id); // LINE 81

    if ($region_info) {
        $product_region[] = array(
            'name' => ($region_info['path']) ? $region_info['path'] . ' &gt; ' . $region_info['name'] : $category_info['name'],
            'href'  => $this->url->link('account/profile', '&path=' . $region_info['region_id'])
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the code which probably causes the error:

```
public function getRegion($region_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "region_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "region_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.region_id AND cp.region_id != cp.path_id) WHERE cp.region_id = c.region_id AND cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' GROUP BY cp.region_id) AS path, (SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE query = 'region_id=" . (int)$region_id . "') AS keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "region c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "region_description cd2 ON (c.region_id = cd2.region_id) WHERE c.region_id = '" . (int)$region_id . "' AND cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

    return $query->row;
}
```

I'd appreciate if you help me by giving a piece of code, because I'm dummy in PHP.

Comment: Suggestion. Do not hard-code it. Try using the CI db class...

Comment: @Fil, What's that or how to use?

Comment: It's not the solution, But I think this could help https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: @Fil, unfortunately I'm in short of time! I just need a quick help and solution!

Comment: Where is `latest.php`'s line 81? It seems that you are trying to call `getRegion` as a member of an object which is Null. `getRegion()` itself seems not to have a problem. For your question: [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) has some interesting stuff about error handling.

Comment: @Clijsters, I updated my question

Comment: `$this->model_account_region` results to `null`. Without some code of it, we can't say why.

Comment: instead of `return $query->row;` try using return $query->result_array();

Comment: @Fil This is a good suggestion but it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I tried both "try, catch" and "result_array()", but the same error!!

Comment: try running the query directly in your phpmyadmin if it will give you the expected result else, you need to revise your query.

Comment: @Kardo Sure. These statements are for error handling. You asked about error handling. Please edit your question (title) if you are seeking for a specific solution.

Comment: @Clijsters, You're right, I edited the title

Comment: Something very strange, I even deleted the whole function, but I still get the same error. I don't know what this means!

Comment: I just had forgotten to load the model ($this->load->model('account/region');) !!! Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: I wonder why PHP returns such a stupid error!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->model_account_region  //This property is null
```

**Check**

```
echo 'FILE : '.__FILE__ .'<br/>';
echo 'LINE : '.__LINE__ .'<br/>';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( empty( $this->model_account_region ) );
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

model_account_region model class is messed up. Since you are running out of time. I suggest you copy the function

```
    public function getRegion($region_id) {
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY level SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "region_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "region_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id = cd1.region_id AND cp.region_id != cp.path_id) WHERE cp.region_id = c.region_id AND cd1.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' GROUP BY cp.region_id) AS path, (SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE query = 'region_id=" . (int)$region_id . "') AS keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "region c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "region_description cd2 ON (c.region_id = cd2.region_id) WHERE c.region_id = '" . (int)$region_id . "' AND cd2.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

     return $query->row;
    }
```

into model_profile_profile then call it from there ie

```
    $region_info = $this->model_profile_profile->getRegion($region_id); // LINE 81
```

if that fails its the db class failing to load properly so you add this line before calling your function on line 81

```
    $this->load->database();
```

let me know if you are facing more challenges. I am a bit bored over here.